# Clustering 2-element integer vectors

Tags: r, intersection

Suppose I a group of 2-element integer vectors, for example each row in this matrix:

```
my.mat = matrix(data = c(1,4,2,5,7,2,3,6,3,8), ncol = 2, byrow=T)
> my.mat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    7    2
[4,]    3    6
[5,]    3    8
```

or alternatively this list:

```
my.list = list(c(1,4), c(2,5), c(7,2), c(3,6), c(3,8))
```

I'm looking for a function that will intersect these vectors with each other and return a `list` where each element is the values of all intersecting vectors. Values of vectors that do not intersect with any other vector should also be return as a list element.

In plain words, this should return this list:

```
list(c(1,4), c(2,5,7,2), c(3,6,3,8))
```

As you can see, the vector c(1,4) does not intersect with any other vector and therefore it is returned as a single element list. The two other list elements are of intersections.

Comment: It always only the first column that overlaps?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use the `igraph` package for this type of problem because it's easy to think of the rows as edges in a graph and you are looking for all the connected chunks.

```
my.mat = matrix(data = c(1,4,2,5,7,2,3,6,3,8), ncol = 2, byrow=T)

library(igraph)
class(my.mat)<-"character"
gg <- graph.edgelist(my.mat, directed=T)
vset <- clusters(gg)$membership

xx<-sapply(unique(vset), function(s) {
    es <- E(gg)[from(V(gg)[vset==s])]
    as.numeric(V(gg)[t(get.edges(gg,es))]$name)
})
```

This turns your matrix into an edge list (the conversion to character is really only needed if you have non-continuous numbers so it works more generally). That makes this graph

[image]

Then then `clusters()` function partitions them into subgroups. Then I go through each subgroup and extract the names of the vertices in the edges of each subgroup.

In the end, the value of `xx` will be

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 4

[[2]]
[1] 2 5 7 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 6 3 8
```

so it's a list of connected values.

Comment: + 10 if I can ! excellent ! I would add a plot of the graph  because really help to see the solution!